# Inject token value to global container in Angular 2, Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject value globally to my application's DI container in Angular 2 according to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens).

However, I'm getting an error:

```text
compiler.es5.js:1540 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:30216:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43553:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43421:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43030:24)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43674:45)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43257:110
    at Array.map (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43257:73)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54306:66)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54265:52)
```

Here's my classes:

## app.module.ts

```typescript
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {InjectionToken, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

export interface AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
  title: string;
}

export const HERO_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'api.heroes.com',
  title: 'Dependency Injection'
};

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

## app.component.ts

```typescript
import {Component as NgComponent, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_CONFIG, AppConfig} from './app.module';


@NgComponent({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (@Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: AppConfig) {
    console.log(config.apiEndpoint, config.title);
  }
}
```

---

What could be the problem and what debugging strategy should I use? The error and stack trace doesn't really help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) stated here: [@Inject() for InjectionToken declared in module fails in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023796/inject-for-injectiontoken-declared-in-module-fails-in-angular2#comment75074097_44023796)

You should move `export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');` to a seperate file since it's causing a circular dependency issue.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion, I will look into it and will try to apply this solution. BTW: is there an issue in Angular about this? I think the error message should be more clear…

Comment: Confirmed. Actually it makes perfect sense from the design standpoint: we shouldn't mention `app.module.ts` in other files.